# query does not include the specified expression 'ColB' as part of an aggregate function

Tags: excel, database, ms-access

I am using this query and it is working perfect but in excel as a database, it is giving me an error of aggregate function -
solution: once I add all column in the group by I don't get sum and Group by doesn't work.

`select ColA,ColB,ColC,ColdD,SUM(ColE),ColF,ColG FROM automate GROUP BY ColA`

One picture indicates table structure:

[image: table]

Another one is expected output:

[image: table]

Please help me if someone knows- MS-Access / excel as database

Comment: You need to either group or use an aggregate function on all of the columns, not just 2.

Answer (score 0):

Every field in your `SELECT` part must be either `GROUPed BY` or aggregated. If all values are guaranteed to be the same or if you don't care which value will be picked use `FIRST()`, otherwise use the appropriate aggregate function (MIN, MAX, FIRST, LAST, SUM, etc.)

Example:

```
SELECT ColA, FIRST(ColB), FIRST(ColC), FIRST(ColdD), SUM(ColE), FIRST(ColF), FIRST(ColG) FROM automate GROUP BY ColA
```

Comment: suppose ColC with two rows have a different value and I want 1st record but when I use group by it splits my sum aggregate function data into two different rows.

Comment: Hi, I tried with FIRST(ColC) function and got the first value available in the row. thanks this solved my problem